# PHP Merge with separators

Tags: php, html, arrays, string

I am trying to merge two strings in a specific way.

Essentially I need to merge the first two strings into a third with a pipe symbol between them then separated by commas:

```
$merge1 = "id1,id2,id3"
$merge2 = "data1,data2,data3"
```

Those two would become:

```
$merged = "id1|data1,id2|data2,id3|data3"
```

I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Answer is below, but that makes me no sense at all. Why strings and not arrays (especially when you used `array` tag)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will help you

```php
<?php

$merge1 = "id1,id2,id3";
$merge2 = "data1,data2,data3";

$merge1 = explode(",", $merge1);
$merge2 = explode(",", $merge2);

$final = [];
foreach ($merge1 as $index => $value) {
    $final[] =  $value . "|" . $merge2[$index];
}

$final = implode(",", $final);

print_r($final);
```

**output**

```
id1|data1,id2|data2,id3|data3
```

Comment: I was wondering if you might know; If an array has multiple values that are '0' is there a way to remove them? For instance $array = "11,84,0,0,485,103,0,0,1"; - So it would remove everything that is '0' but not all instances of 0 as one of the numbers could be '103' ?

Comment: you want to make convert 103 to 13?

Comment: No, so the 103 would keep it's 0. Only places that are just a 0 would be removed.

Comment: @EarlGrey: just add condtion into foreach loop `if ($value !== '0') {$final ...}`.

Answer (score 1):

I mean there is no PHP function that can output what you need.

Code produced desired output could be

```
<?php

$merge1 = "id1,id2,id3";
$merge2 = "data1,data2,data3";
$merged = [];

$arr1 = explode(',', $merge1);
$arr2 = explode(',', $merge2);

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    $merged[] =  $val . '|' . $arr2[$key];
}

echo implode(',', $merged);
// id1|data1,id2|data2,id3|data3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php

$merge1 = "id1,id2,id3";
$merge2 = "data1,data2,data3";
$merge1 = explode(",",$merge1);
$merge2 = explode(",",$merge2);


$mergeArr = array_combine($merge1,$merge2);
$mergeStr = [];
foreach($mergeArr as $k => $v) {
    $mergeStr[] = $k.'|'.$v;
}
$mergeStr = implode(",",$mergeStr);
echo $mergeStr;

?>
```